# perl - compare hash with reference/template hash

Tags: perl, hash, comparison

I have a reference (nested) hash like:

```
$ref_hash = { 
   category1 => {
      key1 => [list1],
      key2 => [list2],
   },
   category2 => {
      key3 => [list3],
      key4 => [list4],
   }
}
```

And a user passed reference to a hash (`$user_hash`). I want to:

1. Check if `$user_hash` has exactly same "keys" as in `$ref_hash`; no more, no less.
2. Check if all values in `$user_hash` are within the respective "listX" in `$ref_hash`. e.g.: `$user_hash{category2}{key3} ~~ @list3`.

I know I can iterate through each key and check it, but for efficient implementation, is there any inbuilt Perl function that can do this? Or at least some parts of this task?

I don't have access modules like `Array::Utils`, `List::Compare`.
I do have access to `Test::More`, `Test::Deep`, `Data::Compare`, `List::MoreUtils`.

Note: My hashes are of varying depth (not just two levels). I have to match all keys of `$user_hash` with `$ref_hash` and also for all leaf (last level) keys - check if their values are in the "range" of corresponding key in `$ref_hash`

Comment: There is no library that'll do something so specific, while `List::Util` and `List;:MoreUtils` will certainly help with some bits. And, with Perl's expressiveness this should be a quick job.

Comment: `Test::` utilities can also help.  Can you not show us what you have already?

Comment: Presumably, the test for the keys (part 1) can be done by comparing the (sorted?) lists of keys from each hash — recursively if need so be. You should have the tools to do that. I don't think I understand what you mean by your second part of the question. Is the requirement that each entry in the list for `category1` and `key1` in the user hash is also present in the corresponding list of the reference hash? How will you report deviations? Messages? Statuses? Just a Boolean condition: 'same enough' or 'not same enough'? Will you need to know which key is missing, or extra? What did you try?

Comment: Is it always two levels, with "lists" only at the second level, and only "lists" at the second level?

Comment: @ikegami - I did not understand the downvoting. When I tried to use some modules, perl is complaining it cannot find them. On the machine on which I am working, I dont have admin rights.

Comment: You don't need admin rights to install a module

Comment: @ Jonathan - I need to report which "key" in `$user_hash` is failing my check. My hashes are of varying depth. I tried using `is_deeply()` & `cmp_deeply()` but they are checking for exact match of hashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub test {
   my ($ref, $hash) = @_;

   my %keys = map { $_ => 1 } keys(%$ref);

   for my $key (keys(%$hash)) {
      return 0 if --$keys{$key};

      if (ref($ref->{$key}) eq 'HASH') {
         return 0 if !test($ref->{$key}, $hash->{$key});
      } else {
         my $val = $hash->{$key};
         return 0 if !grep { $_ eq $val } @$ref;
      }
   }

   return 0 if grep { $_ } values(%keys};
   return 1;
}

test($ref_hash, user_hash)
   or die("Bad data");
```

Comment: Sorry, its not just two levels, depth is variable per category.

Comment: Then how can you tell if you should recurse or check against a list of acceptable values?

Comment: Updated my question with more info.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. How can you tell if it's a leaf?

Comment: its a leaf `if (ref $value ne 'HASH')`

Comment: You should never use that; it doesn't detect all hashes. In fact, it's technically impossible to always distinguish a hash from an array in Perl, so your API is fundamentally flawed. But it it's what you want to do, it's trivial to incorporate in the code I've already presented.